# Powershell hashtable in function not accessible

Tags: function, powershell, variables, hashtable

I created a function to import HR records so they're easily accessible by indexing the employeeID.

```
function hrDataImport {
$HRFile=Import-Csv $rawHRFile #$rawHRFile path previously defined
Write-Host "Creating HR hash table..."
$hrData = @{}
$HRFile | ForEach-Object { $hrData[$_.employeeID] = $_ }
Write-Host "Done. " $hrData.Count
    }
```

I'd like to use that $hrData variable outside the function. I can't reference $hrData['employeeID'] as I've read that variables in functions don't exist outside the function. One thing I tried is creating another function to pass an employeeID into the $hrData hashtable:

```
function showHRData {
    param ([string]$hrUser)
    $hrData[$hrUser]
}
```

I put the functions in a module and imported successfully. I'm able to execute importHRData fine but when I try `showHRData -hrUser $employeeID` I get "Cannot index into a null array". Seems like the function does not see the hashtable variable from the previous function. What am I doing wrong or what would you suggest so I can access that $hrData hashtable across various scripts?

Comment: you can either define the hashtable outside the function so that when it is referred to in the function it is visible by reference. you can also try something like `New-Variable -Name TestHashtable -Value @{} -Scope Script` to create the $Var in your func and have it show up everywhere in your script.

Comment: And you could also return it of course: `return $hrData`. And then call your function like that: `$myHrData = hrDataImport`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create a Hashtable within your function using a `$global` (or `$script`) [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes) like this:

```
function hrDataImport {
    $HRFile = Import-Csv $rawHRFile #$rawHRFile path previously defined
    Write-Host "Creating HR hash table..."
    if (!$hrData) { $Global:hrData = @{} }
    $HRFile | ForEach-Object { $Global:hrData[$_.employeeID] = $_ }
    Write-Host "Done. " $hrData.Count
}
```

But in general it is advised to avoid the global (or script) scope mainly because it might conflict with variables in the current scope.
To minimize this possibility, I would consider to change the responsibility of your function to not only loading the information but also to receiving the concerned `employeeID`, e.g.:

```
function Get-EmployeeData ($EmployeeID) {
    if (!$StaticEmployeeData) {
        Write-Host "Creating HR hash table..."
        $HRFile = Import-Csv $rawHRFile #$rawHRFile path previously defined
        $Global:StaticEmployeeData = @{}
        $HRFile | ForEach-Object { $Global:StaticEmployeeData[$_.employeeID] = $_ }
        Write-Host "Done. " $StaticEmployeeData.Count
    }
    $Global:StaticEmployeeData[$employeeID]
}

function showHRData {
    param ([string]$hrUser)
    Get-EmployeeData $hrUser
}
```

In that case you might choose for a more specific global variable name (e.g. `$StaticEmployeeData`, knowing that PowerShell doesn't support something like a [static variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)) and as an extra bonus the data is *only* loaded the first time you really need it ([lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)).

Comment: I added "return $hrData" to the hrDataImport function and in my script I set a variable equal to hrDataImport. Thanks for the advice.